# How to create multiple dataframes with lapply()?

Tags: r, lapply

I want do same things to create different data frames, can I use lapply achieve?

I tried to did it but not succeed

```
xx<-c("a1","b1")
lapply(xx, function(x){
  x<-data.frame(c(1,2,3,4),"1")
})
```

I hope I can get two data frames ,like

```
a1<-data.frame(c(1,2,3,4),"1")
b1<-data.frame(c(1,2,3,4),"1")
```

Comment: `L <- lapply(xx, function(x) data.frame(c(1,2,3,4),"1") )` It is better to have a list of dataframes than a bunch of many objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option that `assigns` to the `.Globalenv`. This as pointed out is less efficient but was provided to answer the OP's question as is:

```
lapply(xx, function(x) assign(x,data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4),
                                       B="1"),
                           envir=.GlobalEnv))
```

You can then call each data frame with their names.
`a1`, `b1`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `sapply` over the `xx` vector of names to populate a list with the data frames:

```
lst <- list()
xx <- c("a1", "b1")
sapply(xx, function(x) {
    lst[[x]] <- data.frame(c(1,2,3,4), "1")
})
```

Then, you may access each data frame using the list, e.g. `lst$a1`.